# "Bad Realm file header (#1)" Exception when opening Realm file in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, realm-migration

I am using REALM version 0.98.1 (For Objective C), and **sometimes** getting "**Bad Realm file header**" exception while **compressing DB size** on app launch.

Below is the method calling sequence in AppDelegate application didFinishLaunch....

```
[self setDefaultConfigrutaionForRealm];
[self vacuumRealm];
```

Below is the code to Configure Realm:

```
+(void)setDefaultConfigrutaionForRealm{
    RLMRealmConfiguration * defCongfig = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
    defCongfig.path = REALM_PATH(REALM_FILE_NAME);
    defCongfig.schemaVersion = SCHEMA_VERSION; 
    [RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:defCongfig];
}
```

And below is the code to VacuumRealm (Compress DB size):

```
+ (void)vacuumRealm {
@try{
    @autoreleasepool {
        RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
        NSString *realmPath = [realm path];
        NSLog(@"vacuumRealm realmPath = %@", realmPath);

        long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:realmPath error:nil][NSFileSize] longLongValue];
        NSLog(@"vacuumRealm ENTER filesize = %llu", fileSize);

        //
        NSError *err;
        BOOL success;
        NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
        NSString *copyPath = [realmPath stringByAppendingString:@".copy"];

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:copyPath error:&err];
        success = [realm writeCopyToPath:copyPath error:&err];

        if (success) {
            success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:realmPath error:&err];
            if (success) {
                success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:copyPath toPath:realmPath error:&err];
                if (success) {
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:copyPath error:&err];

                    NSDate *endDate = [NSDate date];
                    NSTimeInterval executionTime = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
                    NSLog(@"vacuumRealm cleanup took %f ms", executionTime);
                }
            }
        }
        //

        fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:realmPath error:nil][NSFileSize] longLongValue];
        NSLog(@"vacuumRealm EXIT filesize = %llu", fileSize);
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Inside vacuumRealm exception = %@",exception.description);
}
@finally {
  }
 }
```

While debugging I observed realm path has been configured properly in "**setDefaultConfigrutaionForRealm**" method (Attached Screen shot for reference), but once "**vacuumRealm**" method is called there I am getting "**Bad Realm file header (#1)**" on below line :

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
```

[image: screenshot shows - in setDefaultConfigrutaionForRealm method realm db path is properly set.]

any help to resolve this Exception will really be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a Realm instance (`RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];`) and deleting the file from under it without releasing the instance. This will cause problems like the corruption you're seeing because you're modifying the file while Realm is still accessing it.

Here's an updated version of your method (omitting the debug logs and `err` since it wasn't being used):

```
__block BOOL copySuccess = NO;
NSString *realmPath = [[RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration] path];
NSString *copyPath = [realmPath stringByAppendingString:@".copy"];
@autoreleasepool {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:copyPath error:nil];
    copySuccess = [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] writeCopyToPath:copyPath error:nil];
}
if (copySuccess && [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:realmPath error:nil]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:copyPath toPath:realmPath error:nil];
}
```

Also, whatever exceptions are being thrown in this process are not designed to be recoverable. So the only safe thing to do in the `@catch` block is to abort. Or not have a `@try`/`@catch` clause at all.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, I will give it a try and will revert back to you incase of any queries.

Comment: my code is ARC enabled and I have also added autorelease pool inside vacuumRealm  method, so still does it matter to release Realm instance.

Comment: There must be something else still accessing the Realm outside this autoreleasepool. For example you might have a property holding on to a Realm object or Results, or a Realm itself. Please file an issue at github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new with full reproduction steps and we'll be happy to help.